# G Suite add-on Trigger for Calender eventUpdate should get called when changing event with 3rd party calender app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am struggling a bit with the understanding of the trigger capability of Google Apps Script and I am trying to find out what the capabilities and constraints are.

The idea is to have a G Suite add-on with [Calender eventOpen and eventUpdate triggers.](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers)
My understanding is that those triggers are hit when the user has the extension installed and opens/updated the event. However this would mean if a user changes the event with a calender mobile app, those triggers will not get called.

Is there a way to call them using the Apps Script triggers? I would like to avoid to use the Push Notification since this seems very laborious. Maybe there is an easy way around it?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want an Apps Script trigger that fires every time that a Calendar event is modified. If that is your goal, then you could use the [`TriggerBuilder.forUserCalendar()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forUserCalendar(String)) class to build the [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). On those docs you will find example codes to guide you, but feel free to ask me if you have any doubt.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, maybe you pick it up :) but as far as I understand this, all ways to get ANY trigger for the calendar are for one complete calendar but not for a single event (which is in my case the one I actually need). So If I want only a trigger for one specific event this is not possible. With this trigger I will need to iterate over all events and check if that specific event has changed right?